# C unsigned char ** and unsigned long * to C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm trying to call an external DLL function written in C from C#, this is the DLLEXPORT code from C:

```
DLLEXPORT int DLLCALL Compress(int compressLevel, const unsigned char *srcBuf, unsigned char **outBuf, unsigned long *Size);
```

This is my code from C# to call that function:

```
[DllImport("test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int Compress(int compressLevel, ref byte[] srcBuf, ref byte[] outBuf, Uint64 size);

...
byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
byte[] _compressedByteArray = null;
Uint64 OutSize = 0;
Compress(10, buffer , compressedByteArray, OutSize);
```

However my calling code got an error : "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

Did I make any mistake on my declaration? Any idea to correct this issue would be very appreciate.

Comment: Defect in your code. Try to debug it. We can't. We can't even see it.

Comment: @Ðаn  I have updated my question with C# code. This is a custom dll and it don't have declare information on pinvoke.net.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Try Following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication49
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("XXXXX.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Compress(int compressLevel, IntPtr srcBuf, IntPtr outBuf, IntPtr size);   

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int compressLevel = 0;
            string input = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
            IntPtr srcBuf = Marshal.StringToBSTR(input);
            IntPtr outBuf = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr size = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(long));
            int results =  Compress(compressLevel, srcBuf, outBuf, size);

            string output = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(outBuf);
            long longSize = Marshal.ReadInt64(size);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code didn't generate any error. I'm testing it further more before mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: This code is hopelessly broken. Why did you accept the answer? That doesn't help anyone.

Comment: No it doesn't! Not even close.

Comment: So so many mistakes. Consider just one, the final parameter. You pass a pointer by value. Initialised to null. When the function returns, even if miraculously it avoids trying to write at that null address, your code reads from that address. In effect your code says `Marshal.ReadInt64(IntPtr.Zero)`. Can't you see that is wrong? And this is the tip of the iceberg. The only thing you got right was the int arg and return value.

Comment: Not really. You avoided passing null. But now you leak the memory that you do pass. And the out buffer is not a string, but a byte array. So you need to use the size to determine how much to copy. It's categorically not a string. And C++ `unsigned long` is 32 bit unsigned, `uint` in C#. And you make the same mistake that I originally pointed out in the `outBuf` parameter. And there are many more mistakes. I'm not going to correct them all for you. On the plus side, I'm glad that you have realised how flawed this is.

Comment: There is no memory leak.  And now you are saying things that aren't correct.

Comment: Sure there is a memory leak. Everything I stated in that last comment is correct. Does it occur to you that all the downvotes on your pinvoke answers mean something? What happened when you executed the code above?