# pinvoke byte array from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm trying to move a byte array created in c++ to c# for usage and right now I see that the byte array is valid on the c++ side but I'm getting null back when I move back to c#.

c++ code

```
__declspec(dllexport) void test(unsigned char* t_memory, int* t_size)
{
    int width, height, channels_in_file;
    t_memory = stbi_load("test.png", &width, &height, &channels_in_file, 0);
    *t_size = width*height;
}
```

c# code

```
[DllImport(DllFilePath, EntryPoint = "test", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int _test(ref IntPtr memory, out int size);

public static void Test()
{   
    IntPtr memory = IntPtr.Zero;
    _test(ref memory, out int size);

    byte[] memoryArray = new byte[size];

    Marshal.Copy(memory, memoryArray, 0, size);

    Bitmap bmp;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(memoryArray))
    {
        bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    }

    bmp.Save("test_recreated.png");
}
```

Comment: From the project page: "
Some of these libraries seem redundant to existing open source libraries. Are they better somehow?".  No.  This gets re-invented over and over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ code doesn't return the array because the parameter is declared incorrectly. You pass the pointer but need to pass the address of the pointer instead.

The C++ code should be changed like this to match the C# code:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int test(unsigned char** t_memory, int* t_size)
{
    int width, height, channels_in_file;
    *t_memory = stbi_load("test.png", &width, &height, &channels_in_file, 0);
    *t_size = width*height;
    return 0;
}
```

You must pass the address of the array, not the array itself. Note the similarity to the setting of the  size parameter after this change.

I also include a return value to match the C# code.

You will also need to export a deallocator in order to avoid leaking this memory.

Answer (score -2):

Try code below. Once you exist the method t_size isn't going to exist.  So the memory has to be allocated in the calling method.  How big is your image.  The size may have to be a long instead of an int.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string DllFilePath = @"c:\temp";

        [DllImport(DllFilePath, EntryPoint = "test", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int _test(ref IntPtr memory, ref IntPtr size);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        public static void Test()
        {   
            IntPtr memory = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr _size = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeof(int));

            _test(ref memory, ref _size);
            int size = (int)Marshal.PtrToStructure(_size, typeof(int));

            byte[] memoryArray = new byte[size];

            Marshal.Copy(memory, memoryArray, 0, size);

            Bitmap bmp;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(memoryArray))
            {
                bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
            }

            bmp.Save("test_recreated.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What mistakes?  It should work with c++ code posted.  If it is wrong then the c++ is wrong.

Comment: This is interop. The entire goal is to produce two pieces of code that match along the binary interface. You can't produce one and declare the other to be wrong. You need to make sure that both sides agree. The C# code you present does not match the C++ in the question. The C++ in the question however, cannot return anything, as explained in my answer.

Comment: What doesn't match?  The code should work.  Did you try?  Do you understand what a IntPtr really is?

Comment: Yes, I think I know what `IntPtr` is! Why would I try your code. I know it doesn't match the C++ in the question. I know that the C++ in the question can never return the byte array. And finally, I know that you certainly have not tried to run your code. You haven't do so, how could you criticise anybody else for not doing so.

Comment: The languages are different a declaration have to be different.  The code would still works.  The reason you are asking for help from experts is you do not know how to do it yourself.  So just trust the experts.  You do not know the answers.

Comment: You C# declaration matches this C++ declaration: `__declspec(dllexport) int test(unsigned char** t_memory, int** t_size)`. That's not the C++ declaration in the question. Both parameters and the return value differ! I think I know p/invoke reasonable well: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pinvoke/topusers

Comment: My declaration and code will work.  They are equivalent to your declarations.  The double pointers I'm taking care of in my code.  I'm passing a pointer for the size.  The Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem is creating an int and a pointer to an int.  Then using Marshal.PtrToStructure to get the int.  Yes your solution is a little cleaner, doesn't mean mine doesn't work.

Comment: No. The C++ code in the question does not have double pointers.

Comment: Neither does mine.  but char** t_memory is equvalent to IntPtr t_Memory.

Comment: You just don't get this at all. You don't have any C++ code in your answer. Where in the question, or your answer, is there a `char**`? Nowhere. I give up.

Comment: I know what I'm talking about.  In your answer is the double pointer.  My code will work.

Comment: You don't. You can't address an answer to code in another answer, not least one that arrived hours after yours. And there's only the one double pointer in my answer. Frankly you don't understand this at all and keep writing comments and answers to demonstrate so.

Comment: David : I posted a solution back in March and just got a response that similar code works.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075140/c-unsigned-char-and-unsigned-long-to-c-sharp/43075707#43075707

Comment: That code is just as broken. Hence all the downvotes. The asker accepted that answer to get the extra two rep and stop people nagging about not accepting answers.